# what is the problem that cause this kind of exception: zip END header not found

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am starting Flutter this month and although I have a good knowledge in programing I couldn't solve or figure out what is the problem?
when I start the first app /counter app/ on google chrome it works, on my devices it says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1607)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1497)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1504)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1308)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1271)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:733)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:850)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:191)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

**FLUTTER DOCTOR IS NOT SHOWING ANY ERRORS**,

Comment: "zip END header not found" means you have a defect (truncated) ZIP file. Unfortunately the error does not indicate which file is truncated.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. The error is related to Gradle, this is usually due to corrupt or incomplete Gradle setup

find (.gradle) folder and delete it

then run the application again and wait for new gradle setup to complete
in my case firstly I open an android folder

Or

Step 2:

android>gradel>wrapper>gradle-wrapper.properties

in gradle-wrapper.properties change

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip

```
                            to
```

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error log! it seems that either your gradle or some zip file in your project has got corrupted and has some missing files.

You can try running the

> flutter clean

command and then try running it again

> flutter run

If this still doesn't help then I think you can simply create a new project which will create the files and won't be having any missing files.

Or you can try adding the android and iOS configuration again by running this command.

> flutter create --platforms=android,ios [PROJECT]

Comment: it is new man.....